# Checking whether a list of Permutations form a Group

Tags: group-theory, permutations, gap

I am new to Group Theory and [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) as well. I am given a list of Permutations say

gap> a:=[(1,2), ()]

How can i check whether these permutations form a Group themselves. Apart from the obvious method of, checking equality of Group list generated by a and list a

gap> AsList(Group(a))=a   ?

Comment: `AsList(Group(a))=a` may return wrong result since it depends on ordering on both sides. One should compare them as sets. Or just ask `Size`.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Yes, you are right. I just forgot that. I am trying to implement to group theory in Python, first reading how GAP works for [SymPy](sympy.org).

Comment: have you looked at [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/)?

Comment: No, not atleast till now.

Comment: You meant for group theory right?

Comment: SageMath is Python based and have some group theory functionality, and also interfaces GAP for some more. I don't know the reasons behind the choice of SymPy, but if you would like to do some heavy group-theoretical computations, I'd suggest to use GAP as you would have access to many implementations and data libraries.

Comment: I am very thankful for your help. Actually i am involved with SymPy community in development of Group Theory computation. As for GAP's capability is concerned, wherever i read, i only heard GAP's usage. So i thought it be best if i start learning how GAP works. It really is good to see GAP community doing good work.

Comment: You're welcome! Keep in mind that you may [run GAP as a server and talk to it using SCSCP protocol](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/scscp.html) so you can develop interface from SymPy to GAP. For example, if say SymPy understands matrices but not groups of matrices, you can send matrices to GAP and get back properties of the group generated by them

Comment: See also http://www.symbolic-computing.org/ for more details on the SCSCP

Answer (score 2):

So the question is how to check that a list of permutations forms a group under the standard multiplication of permutations. We don't have to check associativity, but we have to check whether the identity permutation is there, and whether it is closed with respect of multiplication and taking inverses.

This is a nice question, which leads to interesting programming exercises and exposes some misconceptions.

First of all, even the approach suggested in the question does not work:

```
gap> a:=[(1,2), ()];
[ (1,2), () ]
gap> AsList(Group(a))=a;
false
```

This happens because GAP compares two unsorted lists, and they contain same elements but in different order:

```
gap> AsList(Group(a));a;
[ (), (1,2) ]
[ (1,2), () ]
```

If you want to check that they are equal as sets, use `IsEqualSet` instead:

```
gap> IsEqualSet(AsList(Group(a)),a);
true
```

This however will be very inefficient for larger examples, since it will create a list of all elements of potentially much larger group. It may help to turn `a` into a sorted list (e.g. using `Set` ). After that one could even use `Group(a)=a`:

```
gap> a:=[(1,2), ()];
[ (1,2), () ]
gap> a:=Set(a);
[ (), (1,2) ]
gap> Group(a)=a;
true
```

For larger groups, this would work fast in the list does not form a group, but may be still slower in the case when it is actually a list of all elements of a group. Two ideas that one could explore and compare are:

**1.** Instead of comparing sets, compare their orders with

```
Size(Group(a))=Length(a)
```

**2.** Write own code which takes a sorted list, first checks whether the identity permutation is there, whether it is closed with respect of taking inverses and with respect to multiplication. Because the list is sorted, lookup in the list will be fast.

However, both of them may be impractical for very large groups.

Comment: I don't GAP promises that `Group(a) = Set(a)` will hold (that is, the order of elements that comes out of `Group(a)` is the same as `Set(Group(a))`, so one should do `Set(Group(a)) = Set(a)`

Comment: @ChrisJefferson: `Group(a) = Set(a) ` works because it uses "=" method for for a domain and a list from `lib/domain.gi:39`, which is `function( D, C ) return IsSSortedList( C ) and AsSSortedList( D ) = C; end;`. But it also creates overhead by expanding D to the full list of its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try

> G:=Group([(1,2),()]);

G is the group generated by the permutations (1,2) and ().

Comment: You don' understand my question. I want to check does only some Permutation elements list Like `[(1, 2, 4), (1, 3)]` form a Group? (I am not considering them as generators).

Comment: @gxyd a set of permutations $\{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n\}$ forms a group if and only if the group the permutations generate is the exactly the original set $\{\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n\}$.

Comment: I am not talking about the Group generated by these Permutations in the list. I am asking if these two Permutations, finite set {(1, 2, 3), (1, 3)}, does this set form a Permutation Group? I don't want to apply the group operation on the elements in the list(just these two permutations only).